# Removing .html extension from URL

Tags: html, .htaccess, url-rewriting

So I would like to be able to go to example.com/page.html from example.com/page (without the .html extension). I've been looking around and it seems to have something to do with the .htaccess file, but I have no idea how to actually configure the rule. Thanks for the help!

Update:

I've only really tried various suggestions I found online, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

Comment: Can you share what you tried so far?

Comment: @Evert any ideas?

Comment: The first example is a redirect not a rewrite. What happens when you use the second version? (Just in case: what webserver are you using?)

Comment: I get a 404 error. As far as the webserver, I'm not too sure, I use bluehost.

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRUle ^/?(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/?$ /$1.html (END)
```

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

In case you get an "internal server error" (http status 500) using above rule set chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will find a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log in that case. Either upgrade your http server to a more or less current version or try using the older `[L]` flag in that case, it should work the same, though that depends a bit on your setup.

Comment: Thank you, however when I try to load the website now I get the error message:
Internal Server Error
...
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache Server at foodtoyou.co.il Port 80

Comment: I added another paragraph to the question which hopefully fixes that issue you report.

Answer (score 0):

URL example.com/page will be loading content from file /page.html

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
```